# How to prevent Basic Authentication form to popup

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, basic-authentication

I have a application in Java, JSF that uses javascript to connect to a website that needs Basic authentication.

The thing I want to accomplice is the exact same thing that happens when I type in username and password in the popupform.

I have tried many different ways that I have seen on the topic, but none of them works. The strange thing is that the ajax calls return a respone, but then I get the windows security popup anyway. Do I need to cache it someway?
For example the both of the codes below I dont get to work. The one below uses the base64

```
$.ajax(
                {
                  'password' : password,
                  'username' : username,
                  'url'      : url,
                  'type'     : 'GET',
                  'success'  : function(){ alert("success");  },
                  'error'    : function(err){ alert('Bad Login Details' + err);},
                }
              );

$.ajax({
            url : url,
            method : 'GET',
            beforeSend : function(req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
            },
            error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

                alert('Invalid username or password. Please try again. thrownError:' + thrownError + 'xhr:' + xhr + 'ajaxOptions:'+ajaxOptions);

            },
            sucess: function(result) {
                alert('done');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can encode basic-auth credentials in the URL in the following format:

https://username:password@www.example.com/abc

So adapt your ajax url the same way.

Comment: Hi kabram ,and thanks for the post. I found that 

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax(<br> { 'password' : 'your_password', 
    'username' : 'your_username', 
    'url' : url, 
    'type' : 'POST', 
    'success' : function(){ }, 
    'error' : function(err){ }, } ); 

Works only for browsers that allows cross site scripting. Is it possible to solve that for a browser that don't?

Sorry for the bad format..

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of the server side code, you could roll your own Authenticate header to prevent the browser from popping up the standard Basic Challenge.  For example, if you header is:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="realm here"
```

Then the browser will pop up the challenge.  But if you header is:

```
WWW-Authenticate: my-basic realm="insert realm"
```

Then the browser will not pop up a 401 challenge.

Comment: Hi Aurand
I dont have control over the serverside so I guess this change won't be possible. 

Thanks anyway